# Interesting irrational number

Tags: mathematics

Can you find an **irrational** number $x$ such that $x$, $1/x$ and $x^2$ all have exactly the same digits after the decimal point? Good luck!

Comment: Good question, by the way.  It's easy to forget the magic of this number.

Comment: Are there any non-irrational numbers which satisfy this other than 1?

Comment: [You're not the first by a long way, it's a bad idea for multiple reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/) @SlowMagic

Comment: @JamesHurley I know one more rational number that satisfies this. Can you find it?

Comment: -1 (and this is not a downvote!)

Comment: yep that's the one!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first one which leapt to mind satisfies $x^2=x+1$ and $1/x=x-1$.  Upon closer examination, only the positive solution works: $x=(1+\sqrt5)/2$, which is commonly known as $\phi$, the 'golden ratio'.

Comment: Correct and well done! Are there other solutions?

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect not, but my proof had a loophole I'll need coffee to mend.

Comment: $x= \frac{1-\sqrt(5)}{2}$ isn't a solution. $x = -0.618...$. $\frac{1}{x}=1.618...$. which is fine, but $x^2=0.381...$.

Comment: I figured Mr. Gibson's answer below covered for my undercaffeination, but figured I would at least share my lateral-thinking way of salvaging it. ^_^  If you distribute the negative sign across all the digits (so instead of -(6/10 + 1/100+ 8/1000...) we have -6/10 + -1/100 + -8/1000...  then x^2 could (unconventionally) be written +1 + -6/10 + -1/100 + -8/1000...  Seriously, though, good catch (we all need to be careful with sign flips sometimes ^_^)

Comment: I try to make a point of not burying my mistakes, but hadn't considered the broader context of leaving the accepted answer unclear.  Sorry for any resulting confusion.

Comment: Here’s some coffee ☕️ so you’ll be ready for next time.  Cheers!

Answer (score 28):

Proof that the only positive solution is

> $$x=\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\text, \quad \text{ i.e. } \quad x=\phi $$

Let $y$ be a positive solution. Then

> $y^2$ and $1/y$ are also positive and there exists some integers $k,l$ such that:
>
>  $$y^2=y+k \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{1}{y}=y+l$$
>
>  Multiplying the second equation by $y\neq0$ and substituting $y^2$ in the first equation leads to:
>
>  $$1-ly=y+k\text, \quad \text{ i.e. } \quad 1-k=y(1+l)$$
>
>  In that last equation the LHS is an integer, but $y$ is irrational and $1+l$ is an integer, so the only possibility for the RHS to be an integer too is $l=-1$, and then $k=1$.
>  That brings us back to $y^2=y+1$, and thus  $y=\phi$.

Similarly, we can prove that

> $y = \frac{- 1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = -\phi$

is the only negative solution.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Previous answers seem to say that there are two solutions:

$$x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

but for $$x=\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

the base 10 representations of $x$ and $x^2$ are:

$$-.618\dots$$ and
$$.381\dots$$

which do **not** have the same digits after the decimal point.

Comment: right, only as exponent of $e^(i*2pi*y)$, both $y=x$ and $y=x*x$ appear equal in digits after decimal point (both real and imaginary).